# Create vendor class objects in components of cakephp

Tags: cakephp

In cakephp,
I want to import a vendor php file which contains different classes eg(class A class B, class C, each having __construct() method), in my component.I want to create objects of each class in the component and call respective class function in my controller.

What is the correct process to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

component:

```
  class LibraryComponent extends Object {
        public function classA($params) {
             App::import('Vendor', 'library', array('file' => 'classA.php'));
             $class = new classA($params);
             return $class;
        }
    }
```

controller:

```
$myClass = $this->Library->classA($params);
```